# Page_load event not firing but page_init is

Tags: asp.net

I have an aspx page,  it does some work by calling a stored procedure.

If I leave the page for some time and I click a asp.net button the click event does not fire.  If I attach to the process using the debugger and put break points in the button.click, page.load and page.init events then the only breakpoint that fires off is the page.init.

In what circumstances can this happen?

I am using a tcp socket. I am using ajax.  Can any of these things cause this to happen?  Is this just down to timeout issues?

Thanks

Comment: Put a breakpoint in the Global.asax Application_error event. There is probably an error occurring that is preventing the complete execution.

Comment: It is likely the session has expired or something similar.  Do you use any authentication or session control?

Comment: hi, i use a session control.  I could use a heartbeat to avoid timeout but i have not implemented it yet. it is just that i detected this issue a few times now and was just curious what was causing it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

just to close this.  This is just down to the session ending. Sorry to waste everyones time.

on the plus side i have now answered (and been accepted) my first question :)